# Write file to another computer in local network with JS

Tags: java, javascript, file, firefox, networking

Currently I am writing to a file on my local storage via following commands:

```
var localFileName="localFile.txt";
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect');
var localFile = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
localFile.initWithPath("C:\\MyLocalPath\..." + localFileName);
```

Now, if I want to write to a file on another PC in the same local network, can I also use the above pattern and only change the "initWithPath" to the IP (and path) of the other computer or do I have to use a different method or Java implementation?

Note: This only has to be working on Mozilla Firefox, other browsers are of no importance.

Best regards.

Edit: As mentioned in the comments below using Java could be a good solution. At the moment I have the following code (which is working from "localhost" to "localhost"):

```
public static void startSender() {
        (new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Socket mySocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 60014);   // IP, Port
                    BufferedWriter outputStream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(mySocket.getOutputStream()));
                    outputStream.write("it works... ");
                    outputStream.flush();
                }
// (+ catch Exceptions)
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public static void startServer() {
        (new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ServerSocket myServerSocket;
                try {
                    myServerSocket = new ServerSocket(60014);
                    Socket mySocket = myServerSocket.accept();
                    BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(mySocket.getInputStream()));
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                }
// (+ catch Exceptions)
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: I don't think Javascript has write access to the computer, that seems like a major security hole if a browser allowed that.

Comment: So the solution might be to use Java instead? (Socket, BufferedWriter, ...)

Comment: Are you talking about an Applet or Application, because Applets have many limitations as well. If you can get two applications that connect to each other on both machines you should be able to achieve your goal easily.

Comment: I'm not really proficient in such matters.
I have a "Server" class that could be run on one machine and a "Client" class that could be run on the other.
Would that be sufficient?

Comment: Here's an [example](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/216.html). Socket programming with Java isn't terribly difficult.

Comment: Is my approach (compare edited initial post) more complicated or even appropriate for what I want to do? On my local machine it works just fine, but I'm not sure if it will do so on two different computers?

Comment: I don't think so. You may want to keep references to your sockets just for ease of properly disposing of them when you are done (they should be `.close`ed before you discard them. It's worth a shot. Unless you're writing text you might want to use a different writer instead of a BufferedWriter though.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with "You may want to keep references to your sockets just for ease of properly disposing of them when you are done (they should be .closeed before you discard them. It's worth a shot."

And finally: My goal is to write text to a .txt File on the other computer - did I get you wrong when I assume BufferedWriter is appropriate here?

Comment: `ServerSocket server;` and then `Socket client = server.accept();` and then when you're done with a client: `client.close();` and when you close the application: `server.close();` You may also want to store the clients, probably `ArrayList<Socket> clientList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Works just fine if I run it once. But afterwards I always get:
"java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at Server$1.run(Server.java:24)"

Do i have to close the stream earlier?

Comment: That's probably because you aren't disposing of your server socket appropriately. That or you are trying to have to server sockets bind to the same address.

Comment: Okay, I got the idea behind this. I'm facing one last problem: The Server class seems to be terminating after the Client class was run once. Is this just normal? Should not the Server be waiting for incoming Connections as long as it is running?
Error Message:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) [...]

thrown by line "while((clientInput = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {"

Comment: That all depends on how your Server class works. Does it just sit and wait for one accept? Most server's are run in a loop, like `while (running) { Socket client = server.accept(); /* handle new client */ }`

Comment: I worked around that problem for a few days now and was able to solve the Exception above. But still - the Socket closes after one Line was read.
At the moment i have something like: while (inputStream.ready()) {
                  clientInput = inputStream.readLine();
                  System.out.println("Stream: " + clientInput);
                     writeToFile(clientInput); 
                 }
The rest is rather identical to my initial post - and I just don't know what to change...